# Using Python 3.7, how to removed lines with same beginning in a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question is asked so that I can make a tool based on Python 3.7 on my company computer (so installing a new module might not be an option). Not to mention that I just begin learning Python recently...

After running a test program (built by the company), I can extract a txt file that looks like this

```
Test_1     FAIL

Test_1     FAIL

Test_1     FAIL

Test_1     PASS

Test_2     PASS

Test_3     PASS

Test_4     FAIL

Test_4     FAIL
```

My target is to remove the duplicated lines, so that the remaining would be something like this

```
Test_1     PASS

Test_2     PASS

Test_3     PASS

Test_4     FAIL
```

Currently, my plan is to compare the first word of each line with the line after it (so Test_1 vs Test_1 for the first iteration). If it is the same, then the 1st line will be discarded.

The compared part is done as follows (assume final_file is another .txt file)

```
with open("resultFile.txt", "r") as result_file:
  lines = result_file.readlines()
    for i,j in enumerate(lines[:-1]):
      if j.split(" ",1)[0] == lines[i+1].split(" ",1)[0]:
        del lines[i]
        final_file.write(lines[i+1])
      else:
        final_file.write(lines[i])
```

I try to run this, and I have IndexError: list index out of range for the if line. Is there any suggestion or comment on this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have an empty line after every line in your text file?

Comment: Remove *all lines* of which there exist more than one? Wouldn't it make sense to keep the first occurrence and only remove immediately repeated occurrences? That would be fairly trivial: loop through the file line by line, remember the last line you output, if the current line isn't identical to the last line you output, then output that line and remember it.

Comment: `o = None; with open(...) as f: for l in f: if l != o: write(l); o = l`

Comment: @HarshitRastogi No, my .txt file has NO empty line

Comment: @deceze Not quite, I like to keep the last occurrence: For example, my Test_1 is finally PASS, so I want to keep this, my Tets_4 is still FAIL, so I keep Test_4 FAIL here

Comment: Is there a guarantee that tests will always be in order? Or may there be something else between test 1 fail and test 1 pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a clarifying comment:

> I like to keep the last occurrence: For example, my Test_1 is finally PASS, so I want to keep this, my Tets_4 is still FAIL, so I keep Test_4 FAIL here.

*Assuming* here that tests are executed in order/as group, i.e. Test 1 will always fail until it finally passes, and then execution moves on to the next test, so there's no possibility of an order like *1 2 1*, then this will be the most efficient way to keep *the last* result of a test:

```
last = None

with open('resultFile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:  # read the file line by line, no need to read everything into memory
        key = line.split(None, 1)[0]  # value used to decide uniqueness

        if last is not None and last[0] != key:
            # we encountered a different test which also isn't the first
            print(last[1])  # output last remembered line

        last = key, line  # remember the current line and key

if last is not None:
    print(last[1])  # don't forget to output the very last line
```

Note that in the tradition of UNIX tools I'm simply `print`ing to stdout here; you may or may not want to explicitly write to some file there instead. Also, if your input file actually contains blank lines, you may want to add a check in there for that and skip them.

Comment: Yes. This one works beautifully just as I want. Thanks a lot for your help! Thanks for your comment too, I will take them into account (and I have a rough idea on how to work from that).

Answer (score 2):

the issue is with the `del lines[i]`. You are removing a line so the size of `lines` changes. This is causing the index error.

try this piece of code instead:

```py
result = []
with open("resultFile.txt", "r") as result_file:
    for line in result_file:
        if line not in result:
            result.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are identical, you can use a set to remove duplicates.

```py
with open("resultFile.txt", "r") as result_file:
  lines = list(set(result_file.readlines()))
```

`set()` removes duplicates but returns a generator, so you convert that generator using `list()`

Take care, set does not preserve order.

If you want to preserve order, you can

```py
with open("resultFile.txt", "r") as result_file:
  unique_lines = [line for line in result_file if line not in unique_lines]
```

Comment: this can change the order of the list though as a set does not not enforce order

Comment: By using set you lost order

Comment: That's true, but it does not seem to be required in the question, am I wrong? The OP is asking for removing duplicates... I'll edit to specify this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try these method to remove duplicates:

```
def remove_duplications(input_lines: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    unique_lines = []
    for line in input_lines:
        if line not in unique_lines:
            unique_lines.append(line)
    return unique_lines
```

Then try this

```
with open("resultFile.txt", "r") as result_file:
    lines_to_save = remove_duplications(result_file.readlines())
    
with open("output_file.txt", "w") as final_file:
    final_file.writelines(lines_to_save)
```

Comment: Of course -- when data will be larger and it can't load to memory it will need other solution